# How to customize Fluent Assertions error message

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, output, fluent-assertions

I want to prepend a component name and the type information before any errors are shown. Typically I am asserting custom types. I want to know which types are being compared before seeing the rest of the error messages which are focused only on the properties.

For example:

```
[PaymentService] Comparing Org.Payments.Transaction to Org.Payments.Transaction:

> the rest of the error message is here
```

I saw the default `ITraceWriter` doesn't show or allow it. A custom one can show the component name. But given its interface it won't be able to show the types being compared since there is not enough metadata available.

Additionally `Using` doesn't provide means of customizing it.

How should I achieve this goal?

Comment: What values you are asserting and how? What issue you have so you need to prepend extra data?

Comment: @Fabio, I updated the question. I think it is very useful in general and in my particular case to have the type information in the beginning of the error message.